# Wordpress error, javascript not loading to website page jQuery undeclared

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create a functional button, so I can upload a profile picture to the wordpress admin page.

This is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var mediaUploader;
    $('#profile-picture-button').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(mediaUploader) {
            mediaUploader.open();
            return;
        }
        mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose a profile picture',
            button: {text:'Choose Picture'},
            multiple: false
        });
    });
});
```

So, the problems I'm having are:

1. jQuery is undeclared
2. `wp.media.frames` for the `mediaUploader` is undeclared
3. When I inspect my website elements my `admin.js` file is not being loaded

I'm sure there's nothing wrong with my code because I have used it before
I tried everything all the others forums recommended

In my functions.php I made sure to include `wp_enqueue_media` and `wp_enqueue_script` hooks

```
 wp_register_script( 'admin-script ', get_template_directory_uri().'/JS/admin.js',array('jquery'),false, true);
 wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-script' );
 wp_enqueue_media();
```

I didn't include jQuery library because it's already in WordPress
all I did was set the dependency `array('jquery')` to make sure it's in.

I also don't use any plugins so that's not the problem.